# Is there a quantitative method to follow to determine FILLFACTOR for NONCLUSTERED INDEXes?

Tags: sql-server, nonclustered-index, fill-factor

I've read different ideas to set `FILLFACTOR` and then monitor fragmentation over time (**#1:** [5 Things About Fillfactor](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/04/five-things-about-fillfactor/), **#2:** [Database Maintenance Best Practices Part II – Setting FILLFACTOR](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/database-maintenance-best-practices-part-ii-setting-fillfactor/)).

Instead of making an 'educated' guess upfront and then adjusting, I was wondering:

- If anyone knew of a (quantitative) way to determine what level of fillfactor would be needed **upfront**?

(I'm primarly concerned with respect to `NONCLUSTERED INDEXes`, as I typically create my clustered indexes on ever-increasing integers.)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Merely avoid page splits in your non-clustered indexes? I'm not sure how that will be possible - if your data is getting updated then it doesn't really matter what the fill factor was initially.

Comment: My thinking was to delay "major" fragmentation, thereby reducing the frequency with which `REBUILD`/`REORGANIZE` are required. Also, when `REBUILD`/`REORGANIZE` are actually called, that these operations would be faster due to a lower level of fragmentation.

Comment: Any quantitative effort would rely on you having an accurate model of the pattern of inserts, updates and deletes that the index will encounter. Do you have this?

Comment: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/04/five-things-about-fillfactor/

Comment: @MartinSmith, assume they are available, how could they be used to "size" the fillfactor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No generalised quantitative method exists to be followed.

One would'e come up by now (1+ years since question), nor have i come across one on the internet searches.